# Create a column based on another two columns in PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table
[image]

and I need to calculate the mean value of LineTotalNM. This mean value can be calculated by dividing LineTotalNM by Order Qty.

How can I create a new field for my pivot table with that formula?

Note that I don't want to use the regular Excel function for expressions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Note that I don't want to use the regular Excel function for expressions."?

Comment: Your comment to Szilard's answer would suggest that your Pivot Table's source data is from the Data Model, correct? If so, you can create a simple measure within Power Pivot to achieve your desired result.

Comment: @Yes, it comes from an analysis project

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **PivotTable Analyze > Fields, Items, & Sets > Calculated field** give a name to the new column and enter your formula.

Comment: I am trying but that option appears grey (disabled)